# Using jQuery selectors on an object created after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

I am picking up a JQuery project created by someone else(always fun).

It seems the original author is creating a popover on rollover on page elements.  The popover has buttons, e.g. "class=deleteBtn".  Originally, I was unable to get this link to respond to a click with a typical jQuery selector "on" method, so I had to do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteBtn', function () {
        alert('foo')         
    });
```

And that indeed displays the alert.  However, now I need to hide and show elements in this popover, and I am running into the selector issue again.  For example, this does not work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteBtn', function () {
        $('.prompt1').hide();
    });
```

Where prompt1 is the first div in the popover, an ancestor of .deleteBtn.

What am I missing here?

Comment: As long as that element exists at the time of clicking that button, this should be fine.

Comment: might be there are more .prompt1 ... so you are selecting the wrong one

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly, before you start hacking away, **take the time to understand what the previous programmer was thinking**. Don't just slap code on top of code and then get frustrated when it "doesn't work." Respect the efforts of the previous developer. Study and understand their code; get inside their head, and figure out the system that they used to solve problems and meet the requirements.

That being said...

1. My first intuition is that there are other events bound to the DOM elements in question, and often they contain a call to event.preventDefault(). This may be preventing your events from firing.
2. What other events are attached to these elements? Attaching your click event to the document and scoping to the .deleteBtn class is odd; there's something else going on. Is event delegation being used for these popovers? If so, delegated events may be overriding your events.
3. When you say "popover," this implies a separate browser window (remember those old "popunder" ads?). Do you mean this, a flyout, or a modal? If you're talking about a flyout or modal, they may have used a modal plug-in, like lightbox. If so, try and identify which plugin they're using to create the popovers. If they're custom, take a close look at the system that's used to show and hide them.
4. Check your CSS for **z-index** settings. Can't tell you how many times I've been bitten by this one. With an incorrect z-index setting, the div **is** properly showing... but underneath other content! Remember that for z-index to work, the container div must have a **position** style set; e.g. position:relative, position:absolute, etc..
5. Are you getting any errors?

Hope this helps!